# Smooth scroll not working when use it on mouse move inside React component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a code example where I try to scroll elements horizontally on mouse move.
Here is a demo: https://codepen.io/arturtakoev/pen/mdEOVvO?editors=0110

```
const App = () => {
  const propertyThumbnails = useRef(null);

  const mX = useRef(0);
  const mX2 = useRef(0);
  const posX = useRef(0);
  const mPadd = 60; // mousemove Padding
  const damp = 20; // Mmusemove response softness
  

  const handleMouseMove = e => {
    
    if (propertyThumbnails.current) {
      const container = propertyThumbnails.current;
      const parent = container.parentElement;
      const galW = container.offsetWidth;
      const galSW = container.scrollWidth;
      const wDiff = galSW / galW - 1; // widths difference ratio
      const mmAA = galW - mPadd * 2; // the mousemove available area
      const mmAAr = galW / mmAA; // get available mousemove didderence ratio

      if (parent) {
        mX.current =
          e.pageX - parent.getBoundingClientRect().left - container.offsetLeft;

        mX2.current = Math.min(Math.max(0, mX.current - mPadd), mmAA) * mmAAr;
      }
      
      posX.current += (mX2.current - posX.current) / damp; // zeno's paradox equation "catching delay"

      setInterval(function () {
        posX.current += (mX2.current - posX.current) / damp; // zeno's paradox equation "catching delay"
        container.scrollLeft = posX.current * wDiff;
      }, 40);
    }
  };
  
  return(
    <div>
      <div className="empty"></div>
      <div className="parent" >
        <div className="listContainer" ref={propertyThumbnails} onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
          <div className="child">1</div>
          <div className="child">2</div>
          <div className="child">3</div>        
          <div className="child">4</div>
          <div className="child">4</div>
          <div className="child">5</div>
          <div className="child">6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

Also I have an example of wanted behavior:

https://codepen.io/arturtakoev/pen/ZEOBQaR

I am trying to understand why the scroll in my example is not smooth like on second pen.

I tried to use scrollTo with 'smooth', but it's not working either.

Would be really grateful for help with finding the issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found the problem. In case someone will face the same issue, I will leave the question and post the answer:

The problem is that setInterval is placed inside mouse move handler and is reset every time. So the solution is to place setInterval logic to useEffect hook.